# Create an Apex class that calls a REST endpoint and write a test class

Tags: apex, rest-api, trailhead

In the challenge, it is specified :

> The Apex class must be called 'AnimalLocator', have a 'getAnimalNameById' method that **accepts an Integer** and returns a String.

and i cannot understand the line :

```
public class AnimalLocator {
    public static String getAnimalNameById(Integer id){
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals/'+ id);
        request.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
            System.debug(results);
            if(results.size() > 0){
                for (Object animal : results.values()) {
                    System.debug(animal);
                }
            }
        }
        return String.valueOf(response) ;
    }    
}
```

As the debug result, i get ->

> DEBUG|{"animals": ["majestic badger",
>   "fluffy bunny", "scary bear", "chicken", "mighty moose"]}

The expected result must be ->

> {"animal":{"id":1,"name":"chicken","eats":"chicken food","says":"cluck
>   cluck"}}

i am unable to understand the issue!

Comment: I think that your `id` variable must be `null`.

Comment: See http://json.org/ for JSON syntax.The response you are getting is an array of animal names. A REST service might return such an array when you haven't asked for a specific value by supplying an id so check the `id` value you are requesting.

Comment: That's not the case! `id` is not null

Comment: when i browse to the url **https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals/2** the result is fine, but when i try to access from a callout, it isn't returning the expected result

Comment: try with request.setMethod('GET');

Comment: Its difficult to identify cause behind this with information you have shared here. Can you share your complete code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankyou @thatherahere
The issue was here:

In the Mock i mentioned

```
@isTest
global class AnimalLocatorMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
    // Implement this interface method
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest request) {
        // Create a fake response
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        response.setBody('{"animals": ["majestic badger", "fluffy bunny", "scary bear", "chicken", "mighty moose"]}');
        response.setStatusCode(200);
        return response; 
    }
}
```

Instead, it should be

```
response.setBody('{"animal":{"id":2,"name":"bear","eats":"berries, campers, adam seligman","says":"yum yum"}}');
```

I have been placing the wrong text.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem in your method. It is working fine.

As @Martin & @Keith mentioned in the comments, you must check for Id is not null. and make sure you are passing Integer as param to this method while calling it.

```
    public static String getAnimalNameById( Integer id ){
        if( id != null ){
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            request.setEndpoint('https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals/'+id);
            request.setMethod('GET');
            HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
            // If the request is successful, parse the JSON response.
            if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                // Deserializes the JSON string into collections of primitive data types.
                Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
                // Cast the values in the 'animal' key as a object
                Object animal = (Object) results.get('animal');
                System.debug('Received the following animal:');
                Map<String, Object> details = ( Map<String, Object> ) animal;
                String name = String.valueOf( details.get('name') );
                return name;
            }
        }
        return '';
    }
```

and call it as:

```
System.debug( '----> '+AnimalLocator.getAnimalNameById(1) );
```

It will get you the animal name as "**chicken**".

```
USER_DEBUG|[113]|DEBUG|----> chicken
```